# VB.Net Converting from string to double

Tags: vb.net, string, textbox, type-conversion

I have a bad bug in my program where if a user presses the check(calculate) button when there is no input in the textbox the program displays this error: "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid." I would like to resolve this but I am not sure how to do the conversion. I was thinking possibly CType but I am hearing talk of parsing. How do I go about this? the textbox is called mskTxtInput and the button object is called btnCheck which does all the calculation and processing.

Update: This is my code except the parsing method so hope this helps a little!

Private Sub btnCheck_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click
        pic1.Visible = False     'hide picture
        pic1.Image = My.Resources.A
        pic2.Image = My.Resources.F

```
    Dim value As Double
    If Double.TryParse(mskTxtInput.Text, value) = Then
        MsgBox("parsing success") ' parsing worked, so use the value in here 
    Else
        MsgBox("parsing failed") ' parsing failed, so alert the user to that fact 
    End If


    If radAdd.Checked = True Then
        totalNum = num1 + num2


    End If

    If radSub.Checked = True Then
        totalNum = num1 - num2

    End If

    If radMulti.Checked = True Then
        totalNum = num1 * num2



    End If

    If mskTxtInput.Text = totalNum Then
        lblAns.Text = ("Correct!")
        lblAns2.Text = ("Answer is " & totalNum)
        pic1.Visible = True
        wins = wins + 1
        nScore = wins



    Else
        lblAns.Text = ("Incorrect")
        lblAns2.Text = ("Answer should be " & totalNum)
        pic2.Visible = True

    End If

    attempts = attempts + 1
    If attempts = 5 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Game Finished! ", "End Of Game", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        lblAns.Text = ("You scored " & wins & " Out of 5")
        btnSpin.Enabled = False
        pic1.Visible = False
        pic2.Visible = False
        lblAns2.Text = ""
        lblAns2.Text = "Play again?"
        btnCheck.Enabled = False
        btnNew.Enabled = True
        attempts = 0
        wins = 0
    End If


    mskTxtInput.Clear()
    mskTxtInput.Focus()


End Sub
```

Comment: Please share some code where this problem happens.

Comment: This isn't directly relevant to your question, but it looks like you aren't using `Option Strict`. I recommend you turn that on: the compiler then generates warnings about dangerous code that will save you time in the long run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `TryParse` method to do the parsing to avoid getting an exception if the parsing fails:

```
Dim value As Double
If Double.TryParse(mskTxtInput.Text, value) Then
  ' parsing worked, so use the value in here
Else
  ' parsing failed, so alert the user to that fact
End If
```

Comment: Hey! I used your code but made messagebox admendments of "parsing passed" and "parsing failed" and kept receiving the "parsing failed" I can show the code obviously and hope it helps a little!

Comment: @William Mc: You have put an `=` operator before `Then` in the code that you posted, so it won't run. Remove that and it works. I have verified that the code shows the first message box if the parsing succeeds.

Comment: I took away the = operator but it still did not work :( VS always highlights this line in yellow: If mskTxtInput.Text = totalNum Then

Comment: This however stated the parsing worked:   If mskTxtInput.Text = "" Then
            Dim value As Double
            Double.TryParse(mskTxtInput.Text, value)
            MsgBox("parsing worked") ' parsing worked, so use the value in here 
        Else
            MsgBox("parsing failed") ' parsing failed, so alert the user to that fact 
        End If

Comment: @William Mc: You are just checking if the input is empty. As you don't do anything with the return value from the `TryParse` method, you are ignoring whether the parsing worked or not. The messagte box is always shown even if the parsing fails.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks very much Guffa! Although when I run the actual program from the 'bin\debug folder I get the message "unhandled exception occured in the application" when I test it but it allows me to continue without crashing. Is there a way to avoid that altogether though? But again, thanks very much Guffa! :)

Comment: @William Mc: If you are still doing the comparison `mskTxtInput.Text = totalNum` you may get an exception because you are using the string instead of the parsed value, and because you do the comparison even if the parsing failed. As you are comparing a string with a number, it will implicitly try to convert the string to a number, and fail.

Answer (score 4):

Try using [Double.TryParse Method (String, Double)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) rather

Something like

```
Dim s As String
Dim result As Double
Dim returnValue As Boolean

returnValue = Double.TryParse(s, result)
```

Answer (score 0):

dim iVar as integer
dim sStr as string

sstr=""

ivar = val(sstr)

Answer (score 0):

Use the static method [`Double.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx).  If it returns true then parsing was successful, and you can proceed with the operation.  If it returns false then parsing was not successful, and you should show an error message (using `MessageBox` if you desire) and abort the operation.